# How to update existing row in parse.com in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working with `parse.com`.

I saved a `geopoint` in my table `GPSLocation`.

Now I want to update the existing row again and again but the problem is that my given code always create a new row.Please help me for that.

**the code to save data is**

```
ParseGeoPoint loc=new ParseGeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
        ParseObject GPS = new ParseObject("GPSLocation");
        GPS.put("location", loc);
        GPS.saveInBackground();
```

**code to get data and update is here**

```html
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("GPSLocation");
        query.getInBackground("5dL98RycoD", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    ParseGeoPoint loca;
                    loca=object.getParseGeoPoint("location");
                    object.put("location", loca);
                    object.saveInBackground();
                    // object will be your game score
                } else {
                    // something went wrong
                }
            }
        });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: call the same piece of code you used to save